# Modify Regex to work with capital letters & to use numbers

Tags: html, regex

I have this regex expression that I am using for an input pattern="" in html:

```
^(https?://)?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/?$|^(https?://)?([a-z][a-z]+\.)+[a-z][a-z]+/?
```

It works with all variations of URL's & IP addresses such as:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com/
example.com
www.example.com
example.com/
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1/
http://127.0.0.1/
https://127.0.0.1
```

But it doesn't work with any URL containing capitals or numbers with letters. For example:

```
2example.com
example2.com
Example.com
exaMple.com
exaM2ple.com
```

I need my regex to work with all variations of this kind. Keep in mind this has to work for a html input pattern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[a-z]` you should use `[a-zA-Z]` so it will also include the upper-case letters:

```
^(https?://)?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/?$|^(https?://)?([a-z][a-z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+/?
```

Another option is to use the `i` modifier, which (usually) tells the regex to be case insensitive, but you didn't say which language you use (and how you use this regex exactly).

Comment: hey, thanks for responding! What you gave definitely works, so thankyou! Do you have a solution to adding numbers in the regex like stated before in the examples? I also need 2332.com to work also.

Comment: Do you know regex? Did you try to learn? Take my example and think what I just added and what you should add if you want to get also numbers to work there (instead of only `a-z` AND `A-Z`).

Comment: Hey, sorry, I am very new to regex. I have tried learning but it's very confusing because I get the syntax wrong. I think I have found a solution, so thanks for your help.